# How to pass a list of values as parameter in c# databinding

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, dataset, mysql-connector

I've got an Asp.Net application with a MySql database. To access this database I use a dataset (.xsd) where I've put my queries in TableAdapters. One of these queries has a `WHERE IN` clause, like:

```
SELECT somefield
FROM sometable
WHERE somefield IN (?)
```

This `somefield` is a string value. The TableAdapter function expects a string parameter to replace the query parameter. However, I would like to pass a `List<string>` (or an array, or any other type) to check for multiple values. The only way I've found so far is to convert the list into a comma separeted list:

```
GetData(string.Join(",", myList.ToArray());
```

It works fine as long as there's only one value in the list. With two values the query returns 0 rows. I activated the general log in MySql and found out it has to do with quotes. The query that reaches the database is:

```
SELECT somefield
FROM sometable
WHERE somefield IN ('foo,bar')
```

I added extra quotes when joining the values:

```
GetData(string.Join("','", myList.ToArray());
```

But the extra quotes only get escaped and the result still is 0 rows:

```
SELECT somefield
FROM sometable
WHERE somefield IN ('foo\',\'bar')
```

Right now the only option I see is converting every single string into an id and join these integers into a string. Like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8226660/how-to-pass-a-list-of-values-as-parameter-in-c-sharp-databinding) thread. But this means a lot of extra calls to the database to get those id's. I really prefer to use the string values!

Who knows how to solve this puzzle?

Comment: Why aren't you using LINQ?

Comment: Short answer: historical reasons with this application. Longer answer: You started me thinking and I've been looking things up about LINQ. I will definitely take a look at Entity Framework / LINQ in the future!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TableAdapter will keep escaping quotes. You could make a user defined function, which takes a comma-delimited argument and returns it as rows. This way you can access the function as follows. I did this with T-SQL before. It should be doable in MySQL.

```
SELECT somefield
FROM sometable
WHERE somefield IN UDFDelimitedToRows(?)
```

Comment: Yes, that's the route I'm taking right now. Problem is functions can't return multiple rows. So I've created one that compares the string against a list in xml and returns a bool. Currently testing it...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
GetData(String.Format("'{0}'", String.Join(",", myList.ToArray()));
```

If the single quotes get escaped, double them, such as:

```
GetData(String.Format("''{0}''", String.Join(",", myList.ToArray()));
```